# How To Create A Local File Transfer Protocol (FTP) Folder

Tags: windows, ftp

Before this, I have one IP address which uses File Transfer Protocol (FTP) locally. I can directly access to this FTP through my windows explorer simply by typing :

> "ftp://<ip address:port"

and windows explorer will navigate me to a local folder which I can read and write files inside this FTP folder. I am using a static ip address and port **(eg: "192.168.1.21:24)** for this ftp settings. Now, I am creating an application on Windows 10 which will access this ftp folder, but I do not have an environment to test my codes.

I have search Online and everything seems like the environment was not assign locally. Can anyone help to assist on creating this local ftp environment?

Comment: *"I do not have an environment to test my code."* - Unfortunately, this confuses me. If you have an FTP server available at `192.168.1.21:24`, what is preventing you from accessing that server with your code? That is, `192.168.1.21` is a local network IP address.

Comment: Your question is worded in a confusing way and the terminology you use is unclear. Please clarify.

Comment: @Anaksunaman let me clarify on my question. The FTP server 192.168.1.21:24 was available on a different computer platform. I am trying to create the same environment (with same ip and port) on a different computer.